# Magento2 not working after installation in windows

Tags: php, magento, xampp, magento2

I have installed fresh magento 2.41 in windows with xamp. I have followed [this tutorial](https://ccbill.com/kb/install-magento-windows) to install.

After installation I am receiving this error `An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.` while I am accessing either homepage or admin page.

I am accessing the magento site from this url http://mystore.magento.com/. If I access from localhost/magento241 it's showing 404 not found.

I tried to clear cache but it didn't worked.
Log Files are here :

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Use of undefined constant SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES - assumed 'SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento241\vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Adapter\SodiumChachaIetf.php on line 40

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Use of undefined constant SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES - assumed 'SODIUM_CRYPTO_AEAD_CHACHA20POLY1305_IETF_NPUBBYTES' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento241\vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Adapter\SodiumChachaIetf.php on line 40
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Encryption\Adapter\SodiumChachaIetf->encrypt() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php:399]
#2 Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->encryptWithFastestAvailableAlgorithm() called at [vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Type\System.php:339]
#3 Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->cacheData() called at [vendor\magento\framework\Cache\LockGuardedCacheLoader.php:137]
#4 Magento\Framework\Cache\LockGuardedCacheLoader->lockedLoadData() called at [vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Type\System.php:281]
#5 Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData() called at [vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Type\System.php:207]
#6 Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->getWithParts() called at [vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Type\System.php:181]
#7 Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php:132]
#8 Magento\Framework\App\Config->get() called at [vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Config.php:51]
#9 Magento\Backend\App\Config->getValue() called at [vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver.php:109]
#10 Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->getFrontName() called at [vendor\magento\module-backend\Helper\Data.php:209]
#11 Magento\Backend\Helper\Data->getAreaFrontName() called at [vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor.php:50]
#12 Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor->process() called at [generated\code\Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy.php:95]
#13 Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy->process() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Request\Http.php:148]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->getOriginalPathInfo() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Request\Http.php:163]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->getPathInfo() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Request\Http.php:213]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->getFrontName() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php:111]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php:23]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php:264]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub\index.php:30]
</pre>
```

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OJaik33qhQL-X3X26LhFJBtUrk4bU5Cm?usp=sharing

Comment: You should upload logs over here. Question is not clear enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you have installed the sodium PHP extension.

You can check that with `php -i | grep -i sodium`

On Windows

Add "`extension=sodium`" to php.ini (no quotes)
Copy php/libsodium.dll to apache/bin/

Restart Apache

This works for me works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my php version from 8.0 to 8.1 on my linux (centOS) web hosting and had to add the following line to the relevant `php.ini` showing in `phpinfo()`:

```
extension=php_sodium.dll
```

Once I did this the problem was solved!